# Using forced Monospace Terminal font Java AWT

Tags: java, fonts, awt

I want to use `Terminal` face to display read-in strings in my program (on Windows, platform independence not important).

If I use `Font font = Font.decode("Terminal-10");` It is not monospaced.

IF I use `Font font = new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 11);` All is well  but it looks like Courier.

If I use (probably Im misinterpreting the API docs)

```
HashMap attr = new HashMap<TextAttribute,TextAttribute>();
attr.put("FAMILY", Font.MONOSPACED);
attr.put("FONT", Font.decode("Terminal-10"));

font = new Font(attr);
```

it's just using default values (some 12 point plain font). How to properly set attributes to a Terminal font? I'm drawing strings on a `Graphics2D` and saving them with `ImageIO`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you Java AWT doesn't support bitmap fonts at all - judging from what I see in [Font](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html) class - it handles only `TRUETYPE_FONT` and `TYPE1_FONT`. Terminal is a bitmap font, so there's no easy way to use it using AWT's Font machinery.

I'm currently trying to solve a similar problem with rolling my own simple bitmap font engine with limited success in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314672/java-bitmap-font-blitting-1-bit-image-with-different-colors).